# Obtener audio wav a traves de función php

Tags: php

Tengo una **url** en la cual se aloja el audio **wav**, mi pregunta es como puedo obtener ese audio con un archivo y llamar a ese archivo para trabajar con ese audio. La idea es no llamar directamente al audio para poder tapar la **ip**.

Por ejemplo para obtener una imagen jpg lo hago así:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
imagejpeg(imagecreatefromjpeg($url));
```

Entonces llamo a este archivo y obtengo la imagen.

Como puedo hacer algo parecido pero con un archivo wav?

Comment: No está claro lo que pides. Puedes explicar mejor lo que pretendes? Recuerda añadir lo que has intentado/investigado y por que no te funciona o qué errores tienes. Mira [ask] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Aclara mejor lo que estas buscando hacer porque no se entiende mucho

Answer (score 1):

Con esto pude lograrlo.

**Archivo php:**
**audio.php**

```
<?
$url = 'www.algo.cl/audio.wav';

    header('Content-type: audio/wav');
    file_get_contents($url);

    $remote = fopen($url, 'rb');

    while(!feof($remote)){
        echo( fread($remote, 4096));
    }
?>
```

**Archivo HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="audio" controls ></audio>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#audio').attr('src','audio.php');
</script>
</html>
```

Lo que hará será reproducir el audio. 
Al comprobar de donde proviene el archivo, me mostrará la ruta de la que proviene mi archivo **audio.php** y no directamente la del audio que provenga remotamente, por ejemplo de otro servidor.